# Grid cooperatively sharing space

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, grid

I have two elements and I want them to share the available space most efficiently. Take the following xaml:

```
<Window x:Class="Gridtest.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" SizeToContent="WidthAndHeight">

    <Grid Height="320" Width="110" >

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="0" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto" >
            <Border Margin="5" Background="Red" Height="200" />
        </ScrollViewer>

        <ScrollViewer Grid.Row="1" VerticalScrollBarVisibility="Auto">
            <Border Margin="5" Background="Blue" Height="100" />
        </ScrollViewer>

    </Grid>
</Window>
```

This is the result I am after for various height combinations of red and blue, but I cannot work out if this is possible with the stock panels. Using auto for the row heights means that the ScrollViewers do not honor the actual available space. The last example would just be clipped half way through the blue.

[image]

Is there any way to get what I want just using the stock panels, or am I going to have to write my own?

Answer (score -1):

This will give the first row all the free space (after the second one got the minimal space it needs):

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

This will distribute the space between the two rows:

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

This will distribute the free space between the first and third rows in ratio of 1:2 (after the second row got the minimal space it needs):

```
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="*" />
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        <RowDefinition Height="2*" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
```

etc. etc.